# Image and text position issue in LaTex Beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

I am making a presentation in Latex Beamer. I have made many slides but i could not able to fix images and text side by side at the proper location. However which I have made, it is attached below, i just trying to move both image and text in left site. Because there is lots of space in left side which i can't use.

Please anybody share your experience how to take it in left side. So whole space in one slide i can use properly. I have attached my slide and code which i am working.

One more trouble I am facing, When I insert an image into the slide,  how to keep the images as my desirable place e.g. bottom of the page, top of the page.

```
\section{Drought}
\begin{frame}{Drought--Standarized Precipitation Index}
\begin{tabular}{cl}  
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \includegraphics[height=6cm, width=5.1cm]{SPI}
    \end{tabular}
    & \begin{tabular}{6}
        \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%  change the parbox width as appropiate
            \begin{itemize}
                \item{SPI :  The Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) is used index to characterize meteorological drought.
                }
                \item{On short timescales, the SPI is closely related to soil moisture}
                \item{Uses precipitation only; can characterize drought or abnormal wetness
                }

            \end{itemize}
        }
    \end{tabular}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a slide layout I would use `columns`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Drought--Standarized Precipitation Index}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item SPI :  The Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) is used index to characterize meteorological drought.
              \item On short timescales, the SPI is closely related to soil moisture
              \item Uses precipitation only; can characterize drought or abnormal wetness
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the optional argument of `\begin{columns}[T]` you can specify the alignment, in this case they are top aligned.

---

A few side remarks:

- don't specify both the width and the height of an image, the only possible outcome is a distorted image. One length is enough or if you want to give both use `keepaspectratio`
- you don't need `{}` to encompass each item, writing `\item ...` is enough

Comment: Thank you. its really work well. So far I understand slide is devided column 1 and 2. I just Would like to know how to increase the sixe  of column 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @SWAT You can adjust the size by modifying `.47\textwidth`, just make sure that the sum of both columns is < `1\textwidth`.