# Adjust large text paragraph and image in LaTex Beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

i am making a slide of presentation in Latex environment, i am trying  adjust large paragraph text and image side by side in LaTex bemear.but its not adjusting well. whats is the best process to adjust large paragraph and image in one slide.

Below code, i am using, But it's not adjusting into the slide properly.

```
\section{South America Rainfall}

    \begin{frame}{South America (Brazil and Argentina) : Rainfall }
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Monsoon-Brazil}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{1\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Brazil : In their June Crop Report, Conab increased the 2016/17 Brazilian corn estimate by 1.0 million tons to 93.83 million and they increased the 2016/17 soybean estimate by 0.9 million tons to 113.91 million.

                \item Wheat production for 2016 - 17 is projected to be 14 million tons, while Barley planted area is expected to drop somewhat with a production of 3.2 million tons.Corn returns are expected to be very good (and significantly better than soybeans), encouraging farmers to plant 1 million hectares more with a projected production of 31.5 million tons. 
                Sorghum and rice production are forecast to remain practically unchanged.

            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Output :
[image]

After using same value for both column, its looks like, i attached below. line alignment/ justifying can solve the issue.? in left side some space is remaining, how to sift the images and text in left side?

if yes whats the command for line alignment/ justifying[image]

Comment: You seem to have one column that's one quarter of the `\textwidth` and another column that's the full `\textwidth`. I'm not entirely sure how you want to adjust these, but I assume the sum of the column widths should be less than `\textwidth`.

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376170/image-and-text-position-issue-in-latex-beamer#comment931229_376176 The sum of both columns should be smaller `1\textwidth`

Comment: Thank you. Is there any command for line alignment?

Comment: @SWAT: Which lines would you like to align?

Comment: Now i am using the same value `\begin{column}{.47\textwidth}` for both column. But problem all text is not taking into single column. i think if we put line alignment/justifying so all text might take into the column properly.

Comment: @SWAT: I really doubt that you will be successful with justifying. Probably you have to play with the font size (caveat; the result may not be well readable) and the column width.

Comment: @Jürgen   Thanks. i think if we sift / move the image in left side of the slide, hope we will get some space. please would you tell how to sift in left side or how to use full space of slide.

Comment: @SWAT The white space on the left is the margin of your presentation (better not clutter this) and maybe some white space which is part of the image.

Comment: if some space taken by image margin, is there any option available to remove the image margin and keep the image area only ?

Comment: @SWAT see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57420/36296

Comment: @SWAT: I assume you used `\includegraphics`. So please have a look at the manual, especially at `trim` and `clip`. [Or of course to the link that samcarter posted.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

- the main issue with your code is that the sum of both column widths is `1.25\textwidth` - this can impossible fit on a page which has `1\textwidth`. In fact the sum has to be < `1\textwidth` to accommodate the space between the columns.
- If the columns width are chosen sensible the left hand boarder of the image will be aligned with the left hand margin of the frame. In case there is additional white space, this might be from the figure itself and can be removed using the `trim` and `clip` options from `\includegraphics`

Comment: Without the `onlytextwidth` option, the sum of widths of all columns can reach `\paperwidth`...

Comment: Extracts from `beamer` manual: "_`onlytextwidth` is the same as `totalwidth=\textwidth`_" ; "_`totalwidth=⟨width⟩` will cause the columns to occupy not the whole page width, but only ⟨width⟩, all told. Note that this means that any margins are ignored._"

Comment: @PaulGaborit Now I understood you comment. sorry for misunderstanding it in the first place. yes, of course you are right, without this option the columns can protrude in the margins - which they should not do, so I won't emphasise this in an answer to a question which uses `onlytextwidth`